# How to print the required paragraph from a text file in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

I need to print the required paragraph from a text file having N number of paragraphs.

My script is giving the required output, but still I would like to know a more efficient and simpler code to achieve this,

```
awk 'match($0,/ /){print NR;}' para.txt  > temp
para=$1
Para_start=`sed -n ${para}p temp`;
next_para=`expr ${para} + 1`;
Next_para_start=`sed -n ${next_para}p temp`;
Para_end=`expr ${Next_para_start} - 1`;
sed -n ${Para_start},${Para_end}p para.txt
```

Paragraphs have tab space at start of each paragraph.
The above script should run as "para.sh 3".

Comment: Give any inputs and outputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the logic can easily be refactored into a single Awk script.

```
awk -v p="$1" 'BEGIN { r=1 }
    /^\t / { ++i }
    i>p { exit r }
    i==p { print; r=0 }'  para.txt
```

We increment `i` when we see the separator. If we reached past the desired paragraph, we are done (the exit code indicates whether anything was in fact printed). If this is the desired paragraph, print the current line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-awk` you can do that single awk command:

```
awk 'NR==3' RS='\n[[:blank:]]+' file
```